# Windows 10 Bluetooth virtual serial comm port is missing

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, device-manager, com-port

Question: **How to get linked Bluetooth serial Commport installed?**

For communication a serial comm port is needed.
But on some computers, mainly workstations, there is no linked Bluetooth "COM & LPT" with "COMx".

For best comparison we tested on 2 Notebooks. Both from Dell. Both with Windows 10. Both with the same USB Bluetooth dongle. Both paired with same mobile device.

- First Laptop lists all Serial Commports and its working fine.

[image: Serialport available] (**nothing additional manually installed**)

- Second Laptop has Bluetooth but no serial Commports.

[image: Commports missing] (**how to install?**)

We checked the registry but could not find a relevant entry.

How is the installation of Bluetooth virtual serial Commport triggered?

There are many entries to find in internet, but most are regarding a non-working bluetooth hardware, not regarding the serialport. This question belongs to the automatically generated serial com-port.

BIOS Settings on second laptop:
[BIOS01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ279.jpg) - [BIOS02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJv21.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the second laptop have working Bluetooth? Are both laptops identical regarding installed software?

Comment: I updated the question. there are several workstations tested, and laptops. But we could not figure out what is the difference exact. They are not 100% the same. But in internet this problem seems to be common, it would be great to see a solution here. What is the reason and why a Bluetooth device has linked com-port or not.

Comment: Did you check what drivers are being used? In additon as per the screenshots one device has Intel AMT the other doesn't, is that correct? Did you check whenever the BIOS offers options on for this behavior on both devices? As per the screenshot on the device without the com ports it's just detected as a generic BT device?

Comment: Yes, we compared but could not find anything relevant. I added screenshots. You say it is definetly hardware relevant to get serial com-port? Or is it just a common question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an answer...

On any computer not having this work by automation...

`Bluetooth Device RFCOMM Protocol TDI` appears "suspect".

Right click on this and look for "Settings",
I would expect that to bring forth a dialog.

Look for any enabling settings similar to "[x] Load VCP".

This is what is required for some FTDI drivers, might be the case here too.
It may also depend on a "VCP driver", which you may actually need to install!
A reboot might be required depending on the maturity of the code.

Comment: I read your answer and it makes sence for the FTDI driver. In my situation, its using default Microsoft Windows drivers. The RFCOMM looks default for me, I could not find an additional VCP similar tab anywhere for the moment. Thank you for the idea.